# How to use RxJava2 and Retrofit2 in Android Kotlin

Tags: android-studio, kotlin, retrofit2, rx-java2

Now I'm working on android project where I want to read JSON API using Retrofit2 and RxJava2.
I found an example how to do it, but when I'm doing it ***the programm outputs OnFailure message*** and exception: ***E/Surface: getSlotFromBufferLocked: unknown buffer: 0xe84f0220***.

In manifest I added Android Permission INTERNET.
Sorry for a lot of code (
maybe it will help someone in the future).
If you know how to fix this bug, tell me please, or if you have links to good articles explaining how to properly use RxJava2 and Retrofit2 together in Kotlin Android, please post here.

Below is my code.

-- MainActivity class

```
package com.example.rxjava

import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity
import android.os.Bundle
import android.util.Log
import android.widget.Toast
import io.reactivex.android.schedulers.AndroidSchedulers
import io.reactivex.disposables.CompositeDisposable
import io.reactivex.schedulers.*

class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)

        val compositeDisposable = CompositeDisposable()
        compositeDisposable.add(
            ServiceBuilder.buildService().getDataList()
                .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
                .subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
                .subscribe({response ->
                    onResponse(response)
                },{t ->
                    onFailure(t)
                })
        )
    }

    private fun onFailure(t: Throwable) {
        runOnUiThread {
            Toast.makeText(applicationContext, "Failure", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
        }
    }

    private fun onResponse(response: DataListModel) {
//        Log.e("TAG: ", response.items)
        val SIZE = response.items?.size
        for(i in 0..SIZE!! - 1) {
            Log.e("TAG: ", response.items[i].id.toString())
        }
    }
}
```

--ServiceBuilder class

```
package com.example.rxjava

import okhttp3.OkHttpClient
import retrofit2.Retrofit
import retrofit2.adapter.rxjava2.RxJava2CallAdapterFactory
import retrofit2.converter.gson.GsonConverterFactory

object ServiceBuilder {
    private val client = OkHttpClient
        .Builder()
        .build()

    private val retrofit = Retrofit.Builder()
        .baseUrl("http://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com")
        .addCallAdapterFactory(RxJava2CallAdapterFactory.create())
        .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())
        .client(client)
        .build()
        .create(GetData::class.java)

    fun buildService(): GetData {
        return retrofit
    }
}
```

--GetData class

```
package com.example.rxjava

import io.reactivex.Observable
import retrofit2.http.GET

interface GetData {
    @GET("/posts/1/comments")
    fun getDataList(): Observable<DataListModel>
}
```

--DataListModel (Serialize class)

```
package com.example.rxjava

import com.google.gson.annotations.SerializedName

data class DataListModel(
    val items: ArrayList<UserItemsList>? = null
)

data class UserItemsList(
    @SerializedName("userId")
    val userId: String? = null,

    @SerializedName("id")
    val id: Int = 0,

    @SerializedName("title")
    val title: String? = null,

    @SerializedName("body")
    val body: String? = null
)
```

Comment: The `E/Surface` is likely not a problem with your app but just some logcat background radiation. Have a look at the exception itself in your `onFailure` (e.g. log the exception) to learn more about what goes wrong.

Answer (score 0):

I suspect the issue to be here (happened to me few times in the past as well):

```
.baseUrl("http://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com")
```

According to documentation:

> public Retrofit.Builder baseUrl(okhttp3.HttpUrl baseUrl) ...
>
> Base URLs should always end in /.
>
> A trailing / ensures that endpoints values which are relative paths
> will correctly append themselves to a base which has path components.
>
> Correct:
> Base URL: http://example.com/api/
> Endpoint: foo/bar/
> Result:
> http://example.com/api/foo/bar/
>
> Incorrect:
> Base URL: http://example.com/api
> Endpoint: foo/bar/
> Result:
> http://example.com/foo/bar/
>
> This method enforces that baseUrl has a trailing /.

Your baseUrl is missing trailing `/`, and should be:

```
.baseUrl("http://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/")
```

Also update your code to log the error to console, you should see then in the logs which specific error it was (and most probably it is the one I mentioned above):

```
...
{t ->
    Log.e("Failure", t.message)
    onFailure(t)
}
```

Otherwise, your rx code seems fine.

**UPDATE**

You should check if your data model is designed correctly. The `http://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts/1/comments` returns list of items:

```
{
    "postId": 1,
    "id": 1,
    "name": "id labore ex et quam laborum",
    "email": "Eliseo@gardner.biz",
    "body": "..."
}
```

i.e. there's no title or userId